# Composition of two linear and continuous operators is linear and continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

Let $E,F,G$ are normed spaces, $T\in\mathcal{L}(E,F), \ S\in\mathcal{L}(F,G)$.
Prove that $S\circ T\in\mathcal{L}(E,G)$, where $\mathcal{L}(A,B)$ is a set of linear and continuous operators from $A$ to $B$.

The linearity is trivial, I would like to ask if my proof of continuity is valid. Even though there are some proofs of this (and more general), my goal was to understand if I manipulate properly with the notions of norms and continuity.

Proof:
$$
S\in\mathcal{L}(G,F)\implies \forall \varepsilon>0\ \exists\delta>0: ||Tx_1-Tx_2||_F<\delta\implies ||S\circ Tx_1-S\circ Tx_2||_G<\varepsilon \ \ \forall Tx_1, Tx_2\in F \ \ (\forall x_1,x_2\in E, \forall T\in\mathcal{L}(E,F))
$$
Therefore
$$
\forall\varepsilon>0 \ \exists\delta>0: ||T||_{\mathcal{L}(E,F)}||x_1-x_2||_E<\delta \implies ||S\circ Tx_1-S\circ Tx_2||_G<\varepsilon 
$$
Moreover, since $T$ is bounded, for every $\varepsilon$ we can choose $\frac{\delta}{||T||_{\mathcal{L}(E,F)}}$ and continuity condition will be satisfied.

Comment: Yes it is, but why bother about norms, and even operator norms? Don't you know that the composition of *any* continuous maps is continuous?

Comment: Anyway, here is a smarter proof in your particular case: [The operator norm of the composition of linear bounded operators between Banach spaces.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3005389/the-operator-norm-of-the-composition-of-linear-bounded-operators-between-banach)

Comment: @AnneBauval thanks for the comment. I follow the course of functional analysis and my goal in this proof was to understand if I manipulate well with the norms and continuity. Regarding to the proof you linked to, it shows that the operator is linear and bounded and therefore continuous

Comment: I understand. And yes it shows that, this is why I linked to it. And also because I found it "smarter" in two ways: the style of the proof, and the more precise result $\|S\circ T\|\le\|S\|\|T\|.$